# How can I run sql such as “DELETE FROM table_name WHERE name LIKE '%abc%' AND name LIKE '%def%'” by using Android Room?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to delete more than one items by conditions in just one database IO operation. But it seems like Room not support. I noticed [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery) method, but it can only read.

I refuse to use `@RawQuery` to select and delete the result, or run delete method in conditions loop, unless there has no better way.

Maybe someone can help me? I would thanks a lot.

Comment: You can do it like `@Query("your_query")`

Comment: @rahat but you can not do like this: 
`@Query(query) fun myQuery(query: String)`